# cannot connect cluster in amazon documentdb

Tags: ssh, tunnel, aws-documentdb

I am struggling with this issue for a few days, I am trying to connect my db from Robo 3t and  Studio 3t, but i got same error with both programs:
**Note**: I can access by ssh from my terminal, it means that the certificate is fine, the EC2 endpoint is fine, port etc... then the problem should be in another place, right?

**SSH Tunnel error: I/O error: Not ASN.1 data**

Stacktrace:
|*/ SSH Tunnel error: I/O error: Not ASN.1 data
|*___/ I/O error: Not ASN.1 data

But I as i said before, I can connect by ssh without any issue:
ssh -i "cert.pem" ec2-muyser@ec2-54-244-36-226.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

I checked all the steps described in the AWS article below, an I also disabled TLS in the cluster param, as suggested in point 5, but I still having the issue.

https://aws.amazon.com/es/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/documentdb-cannot-connect/

I just edit the post to add a few screenshot from my Robo 3t config:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
Regards.

Comment: I can help you with this. What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I verified the same steps. I am able to connect successfully .

Looks like you are on macOS and you didn't select Self-signed Certificate as  recommended in documentation -
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/robo3t.html

These are two additional  settings which you require to do on macOS.

i) If you are on Linux/macOS client machine, you might have to change the permissions of your private key using the following command:

> chmod 400 /fullPathToYourPemFile/.pem

ii) if you are on macOS Catalina or above, choose Self-signed Certificate as the Authentication Method because the macOS does not accept certificates with validity greater than 825 days.